# How to deep clone a batch class?

Tags: batch, class, related-list, clone

I have tried deep cloning on the opportunity object which has closed won stages it will also clone the Related Products
 I have tried cloning the opportunity and it works okay,how will i deep clone it?

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope1){

        List<Opportunity> cons = new List<Opportunity>();
        //Opportunity op1 = new Opportunity();
        for(Opportunity p : Scope1){  
              if(p.StageName == 'Closed Won' && p.RecordTypeId == '0122v000000vvSPAAY')
              { 
                 Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
                        opp = p.clone();
                        insert opp;
              }    

        }  
              //insertAccountsAndContacts(op1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native "deep clone" functionality in Apex. Your batch class will need to implement this functionality. In rough outline, it would go like this:

- Query Opportunities, using subqueries to include desired line items or other child objects.
- Iterate over query. For each record, clone the Opportunity, and add the clone to a `Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap` keyed under the Id of the original Opportunity.
- After the `for` loop, do `insert oppMap.values()`.
- Iterate over the queried Opportunities again. In each iteration of the loop, iterate over each child object, such as Opportunity Line Items. Clone each child record and accumulate a `List<OpportunityLineItem>`. For each child record, set its parent Opportunity to the clone of its parent by indexing into `oppMap` with the original parent Id.
- Outside all loops, insert the lists of child objects.

Your current implementation runs DML in a loop, which you should never do as it squanders limits and will reduce the performance of your batch class by requiring a much lower batch size.

The filters you perform in your `execute()` method should probably be in the query executed in `start()` instead.